# Remove first n words from string

Tags: php, string, substring, cpu-word, truncation

I'm wanting to remove the first three items from a string,  but the problem is I can't use `substr()` because I don't know how many characters each word may contain since the data is coming from UI

ie;

```
$str = A big brown fox jumped over the log;
//$str = A slow red fox jumped over the log;
//$str = An enthusiastic brown fox jumped over the log;
```

I'd like to remove the first three words (including spaces) so the new string starts with "fox" then I plan on storing this data in a new variable.

I'm hoping there's an easier way than exploding this and removing 0,1 and 2 from the array all of which I am unfamiliar with and if anyone knows how to one line this I'd be most appreciative if you'd share with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a simple split on space to differentiate words

```
$str = 'A big brown fox jumped over the log';
$rest = preg_split('/ /',$str, 4)[3];
```

Modify the regexp if you want to adjust for punctuation marks as well

If you're on a version of PHP that doesn't support array dereferencing:

```
$str = 'A big brown fox jumped over the log';
$split = preg_split('/ /',$str, 4);
$rest = $split[3];
```

Comment: Why `preg_split` for this simple task?

Comment: Reasons why regexp: OP's request for "Without explode()"

Comment: @MarkBaker: Okay. You might want to mention that this works only on PHP versions that support array dereferencing :)

Comment: Wow... So little, yet so much... Asking from a performance stand point, which method do you guys think would be fastest for converting upwards of 100+ strings (as well as those which will come in in the future)?

Comment: 100+ strings isn't a lot, probably barely enough to even notice any difference in performance.... but where's this data coming from and why do you need to remove the first three words, there may be a better solution upstream

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm referencing a feed of items for sale but Im wanting to cut the first several words off as these often carry info a user likely would not be interested in (or care about) when displayed  on my site

Answer (score 1):

```
echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $str), 3));
```

The output will be `fox jumped over the log` for all three strings.

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/64608)

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient and indirect to generate a temporary array to merely cut the first n words from the front of a string.  Just use `preg_replace()` to match and remove n number of non-whitespace sequneces followed by a whitespace character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VSqB1))

```
$str = 'A big brown fox jumped over the log';

var_export(
    preg_replace('/^(?:\S+\s){3}/', '', $str)
);
// 'fox jumped over the log'
```